# How to execute different script in python at the same time based on the availability of the table?

Tags: python, sql-server

I have table A, table B, table C, table D, table E for example and

```
addition.py script(perform addition between two tables on particular columns)
subraction.py script (perform subraction between three tables on particular columns)
additionsubraction.py script (perform what addition.py and subraction.py does in a single script itself basically).
```

I have write a script where it has to detect table on its own and perform relevant script as below,

```
1. if table A and table C is present in the database, then perform addition.py script
2. if table B, table D and table E is present in the database, then perform subraction.py script
3. if all the table A, table B, table C, table D, table E are present in the database, then perform additionsubraction.py script
```

Please any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Query the catalog like this

```
select name
from sys.tables
where name in ('A','B','C','D','E')
order by name
```

That will return an ordered resultset with the names of the existing tables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I trigger those scripts?

Comment: How do you run python scripts?  or How do you run SQL Queries in Python?

Comment: Python query has to detect if the table A and C is present in the DB, then run addition.py scripts and so on as mentioned in the question

Comment: if table A and table c is present in the DB, then maybe call the script in this way like,os.system('addition.py')

Comment: You can run SQL Server queries with pyodbc. https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/